# cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' as parameter 'gamma_1' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)

Tags: pytorch

I cannot make self.gamma_1
My code is :

```
 def __init__(self, dim,initial_values = 1e-4) 
        self.gamma_1 = nn.Parameter(init_values * torch.ones((dim)),requires_grad=True)
```

I have tried

```
self.gamma_1 = nn.Parameter(init_values * torch.ones(dim,dtype=torch.float,device=device))
```

but it did not work.
My environment is python 3.8.5, PyTorch '1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

###### Option 1

Firstly, build the model then you can move the model to `GPU` from `CPU` and all parameters of the model also will be moved to `GPU`. For example:

```py
class Sample(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Sample, self).__init__()
    self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5))
  
  def forward(self, x):
    return self.gamma(x)
```

Now let's check it:

```py
net = Sample()
print(next(net.parameters()).is_cuda) # False, so it is on CPU

net.cuda()
print(next(net.parameters()).is_cuda) # True, so it is now on GPU

# Let's check the `gamma`
print(net.gamma.device)
# you'll get: device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

Or you may create like this

###### Option 2

```py
class Sample(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Sample, self).__init__()
    self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5, device='cuda:0'))
  
  def forward(self, x):
    return self.example(x)

net = Sample()
print(next(sam.parameters()).is_cuda)
# True
print(net.gamma.device) # device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

###### Option 3

```py
class Sample(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Sample, self).__init__()
    self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5).cuda())
  
  def forward(self, x):
    return self.example(x)

net = Sample()
print(next(net.parameters()).is_cuda)
# True
print(net.gamma.device) # device(type='cuda', index=0)
```